# Recode multiple responses into one in R

Tags: r

I want to search for anything that has a "3" in it, and replace it with "3D".
I played around with gsub and stringr, but don't seem to be able to get the regexes correct. Any help would be great! I've been spending way too long on this.

```
type_3d <- as.matrix(c("3D","3D","3D Column","3D Plot","3D Scatter","3D Plot","3D   Scatter","3d Column"))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Andrie has a good answer for your question.

While what you're looking for can solve a specific problem, the general problem of finding all of these kinds of messy things in your data is rather tedious in R.  There are tools designed specifically for doing that though.  You might want to look at [Google Refine](http://code.google.com/p/google-refine/).

Comment: Thank you. I'll keep that in mind. It just seemed like a useful thing to know how to do. Thank you for the response, though. I appreciate it.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure I understand you correctly, since this what you describe is a really simple use of `gsub`:

```
gsub("3", "3D", type_3d)
     [,1]         
[1,] "3DD"        
[2,] "3DD"        
[3,] "3DD Column" 
[4,] "3DD Plot"   
[5,] "3DD Scatter"
[6,] "3DD Plot"   
[7,] "3DD Scatter"
[8,] "3Dd Column"
```

Or perhaps you meant:

```
> gsub(".*3.*", "3D", c(type_3d, "Some other text without a three"))
[1] "3D"                              "3D"                             
[3] "3D"                              "3D"                             
[5] "3D"                              "3D"                             
[7] "3D"                              "3D"                             
[9] "Some other text without a three"
```

Comment: Thanks so much! I just couldn't get the regex commands right. Thank you!